# Panorama hotspot implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, panoramas

I've recently developed an application that view a panorama 360 image, using [Panoramagl](http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/) library for iPhone, and i wanna enhance it and make more features like hotspot.

I've tried to look at a `javascript` code that implement this feature, but it's useless.

**I don't know from where to start implementing this feature and i don't understand the concept of the hotspot. can anyone put me on the right way to start implementing this feature ?**

thx in advance.

Comment: If you don't understand the concept of the hotspot, how do you know you want/need to use it?

Comment: cause i see the hotspot feature in other app and HTML5/CSS3 libraries and the part that i can't understand it is how the hotspot work on the panorama view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up using a library called [KRPano](http://krpano.com/) using it in UIWebView, it has a good support and has a lot of features.

Comment: Does it have support for spherical panorama images, or only cubical ones? It seems to me that cubical panoramas have too much distortion.

Comment: it support all type of panorama image, you can check the supported/unsupported feature via <http://krpano.com/iphone/#supportedfunctionality>

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it actually says "spherical / cylindrical and partial panos is not possible". So I guess I have to make a choice between hotspot but distorted image (KRPano), or no hotspot but with spherical panorama (PanoramaGL) then.

Answer (score 1):

PanoramaGL for iOS was updated recently to 0.1 r3 version. This new version support Spherical images 2048x1024 pixeles. And hotspots feature was added.

http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl

Please read wiki section

http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/wiki/UserGuide

Comment: Yes, I know about it a week ago, but i've didn't check it yet. Thanks for posting.